# Условия в запросах

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `logs` WHERE `id`='$id'",$db);
```

1. Обычный запрос, все работает. Можно ли каким-то образом запросить id='всё' . т.е. я конечно понимаю, можно `WHERE` не писать, но вопрос не в этом. Если по каким-то причинам мне нужен такой запрос, как его прописать? `WHERE id='???'`
2. Из этой же темы. Допустим, нужно `WHERE id='все значения кроме равных $a и $b'`. Такой запрос можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

a)

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `logs` WHERE `id` not null",$db);
```

b)

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `logs` WHERE 1",$db);
```

c)

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `logs` WHERE `id`=`id`",$db);
```

2)

a)

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `logs` WHERE `id`!='$id1' AND `id`!='$id2'",$db);
```

b)

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `logs` WHERE `id` NOT in ('$id1','$id2')",$db);
```

Comment: второе точно да. спасибо. а вот первое, есть что то в роде WHERE `id`='=all' ? (хотя указанный вариант тоже сойдет)

Comment: Легко. WHERE \`id\` = \`id\`